# Why are my jalapenos turning brown?

Tags: jalapenos

Why are my jalapenos turning brown?  The plant looks healthy.  The fruit turns brown after it is about inch and a half from tip to stem.

Comment: Could you upload a couple of photos, one of the plant and one of the peppers themselves?  It could be a disease [as suggested](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/7627/26), or it could simply be that they're ripening.

Answer (score 3):

It may be blossom end rot, does it look like this: http://www.caes.uga.edu/applications/publications/files/html/C938/images/Figure7.jpg ?

If it is, blossom end rot is caused by a lack of calcium to the plant.

- Have you had your soil tested?  It might show that you need to increase the calcium in the soil.  There are plenty of organic fertilizers that are aimed for tomatoes & vegetables that will contain calcium.
- Have you been over fertilizing with high nitrogen fertilizers?
- Are you watering enough?  Water is needed to bring the calcium up through the roots.

You can check out this publication http://www.caes.uga.edu/publications/pubDetail.cfm?pk_id=7801 for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I have never had BER with peppers but with tomatoes I find it helps to pinch off the first few flowers of the summer to give the plant a chance to develop a good root system before attempting to support fruits.  As suggested above good watering practices can also be a factor.